# how can I close a modal from another component in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-services

Is there a way to close angular material modal from another component? I've tried it using a service but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code.

modal.service.ts

```
private modalClose = new Subject<any>();

setModalClose(){
    this.modalClose.next();
} 

getModalClose(){
    return this.modalClose.asObservable();
}
```

sending file.ts

```
onClick(){
    this.modalService.setModalClose();
}
```

receiving file.ts

```
subscribe: Subscription;

constructor(
    private _modalService: ModalService
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SaveDashboardModalComponent>){

    this.subscribe = this._modalService.getModalClose()
    .subscribe(()=>{
        this.dialogRef.close();
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog)

setModalClose(){
    this.dialog.close();
} 

// Here will be good if you open the dialog.

openModal() {
this.dialog.open(name of the dialog Component);
```

And then in another component only call.

```
this._modalService.setModalClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually im using angular 13 so if you need :

At the component from where you want to close the dialog you just declare on your constructor :

```
constructor(private dialog : MatDialog) { }
```

and then in some function or where you want to close the dialog call :

```
this.dialog.closeAll();
```